# Is there a tangible performance benefit to narrowing the scope of document.getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web application that makes heavy use of document searches and I'm wondering if there is a performance benefit to justify converting document.getElementsByClassName to a narrower search such as $container.getElementsByClassName?

I know there won't be a significant advantage but I'm wondering if there's any tangible benefit at all.

As a note, I'm not using any libraries or dependencies so everything is native js.

I also understand that it will vary based upon the number of DOM nodes and a lot of other factors as well.  Let's assume the average web application.

Thanks!

Comment: What is "heavy use" here? What's an estimate? Are you noticing speed issues?

Comment: Well, I suppose heavy use is relative, I mean for like 10 queries of the dom.

Comment: You would only see a difference if you were doing it hundreds of thousands of times in a loop or something. I wouldn't worry about optimizing 10 queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing the same class element over and over again, then caching the container would be beneficial performance-wise. If you only need to interact with that class once, then I wouldn't say there will be any real performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience - yes, there is, especially on large pages.

Another benefit from narrowing the scope would be improved readability. It's basically the same thing as "global vs local variables".

Comment: That makes it sound like `document` is evil. I wouldn't be quite so dogmatic. Assuming average web application would mean there won't be much difference speed-wise.

Comment: Not at all. Global vars also have valid use cases. But in general it is better to stick with local ones.